# I was trying to make a DLL Injector with C# Windows Form App and watched a tutorial on it but now I got one error [CS1503]

Tags: c#, error-handling, dll-injection

> "Failed converting from System.IntPtr to byte[]"

I was trying to code an DLL injection but I didn´t workes as shown in the video...
Does anybody know how to fix this or if I need to add anything to the code???

I spent like 2 hours looking for a fix but I cant find it and I don´t know what I could do so I was thinking one of you could solve this problem?

This is my second Program I have programmed, show some specs of my Computer

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Process_Hijacker
{
    public partial class ProcessHijacker : Form
    {


        public ProcessHijacker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                processlist.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }


        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            DLLP = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private static string DLLP { get; set; }
        private static string PN { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Injection Define
        static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesireAccess, int bintheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBAseAddress, byte[] Buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hprocess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadID);

        public static int Injection(string PN, string DLLP)
        {
            // 1 = Datei existiert nicht
            // 2 = Prozess nicht aktiv
            // 3 = Injektion Fehlgeschlagen
            // 4 = Injektion Erfolgreich

            if (!File.Exists(DLLP)) { return 1; }

            uint _procid = 0;
            Process[] _procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < _procs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_procs[i].ProcessName == PN)
                {
                    _procid = (uint)_procs[i].Id;
                }
            }

            if (_procid == 0) { return 2; }

            if (!SI(_procid, DLLP))
            {
                return 3;
            }

            return 4;
        }

        public static bool SI(uint P, string DLLP)
        {
            IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, P);

            if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO) { return false; }

            IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)DLLP.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0x40);

            if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DLLP);

            if (WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            CloseHandle(hndProc);

            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this program? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: PInvoke declaration is wrong `static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);`. There are many other issues, not least the complete lack of error handling/defensive coding.

Comment: Did you look at sample code at www.pinvoke.net?